Any way to set up an internal unauthenticated proxy for an authenticated rubygems repo?
I'd like to use my private GitHub Packages repo (e.g. https://rubygems.pkg.github.com/myorg), which requires authentication, as the final/upstream source, but have a proxy server on an internal network that does not require authentication, and is able to serve those private packages. The reason for this is to make it easier to build images without having to pass credentials to the CI system or bake them into the image.
I have Sonatype Nexus, and have set up a proxy repo, but it doesn't seem to be able to do the authentication part on my behalf. We had a similar issue with golang, and found Athens to provide that authentication; is there something similar for rubygems?
In the end, I think I'd like to be able to set up a bundler mirror, without having clients provide credentials. Something like this:
$ bundle config mirror.https://rubygems.pkg.github.com/myorg http://nexus.internal.example.com/repository/rubygems


Turns out, the Nexus repository's HTTP Authentication section does work, and solves this issue. I must have been using incorrect or unauthorized credentials. The username should be your Github username, and the password a personal access token (classic) with the "read:packages" permission.
The setup can be easily tested by curling the /versions endpoint, which will just be proxied to GitHub Packages:
$ curl http://nexus.internal.example.com/repository/rubygems/versions
---
my_gem_name 1.0.0 <sha>

Once that's set up, there are 2 ways to use this Nexus proxy repo:

Directly:
# Gemfile
source 'http://nexus.internal.example.com/repository/rubygems' do
  gem 'my_gem_name', '1.0.0'
end


Or as a "mirror":
# In your Gemfile:
source 'https://rubygems.pkg.github.com/myorg' do
  gem 'my_gem_name', '1.0.0'
end


# Then run the following command:
$ bundle config mirror.https://rubygems.pkg.github.com/myorg http://nexus.internal.example.com/repository/rubygems

# Optionally, run this to fall-back if Nexus is down:
$ bundle config mirror.https://rubygems.pkg.github.com/myorg.fallback_timeout 3


# A third, but less explicit option is to use an environment variable.
# Note that everything using the hostname matches, not just sources with the hostname + path.
# (So everything on GithHub packages, not just your org.)
# This should only be used if you are unable to run the bundle commands above.
$ export BUNDLE_MIRROR__RUBYGEMS__PKG__GITHUB__COM='http://nexus.internal.example.com/repository/rubygems'



